# How to maintain sort order with xargs and gunzip

Tags: find, sort, xargs, gzip, gunzip

I'm attempting to extract the contents of some files by alphabetical (which in this case also means date and iteration) order and when I test the process first with `ls`:

```
$ find /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/ -name 20* -type f -mtime -3 -print0 \
   | sort | xargs -r0 ls -l | awk -F' ' '{print $6 " " $7 " " $9}'
```

I get a positive result:

```
Aug 18 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-17-3.log.gz
Aug 18 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-18-1.log.gz
Aug 19 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-18-2.log.gz
Aug 19 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-19-1.log.gz
Aug 20 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-19-2.log.gz
Aug 20 /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-20-1.log.gz
```

However, when I go to actually extract the files the sort order is lost:

```
$ find /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/ -name 20* -type f -mtime -3 -print0 \
   | sort | xargs -r0 gunzip -vc | grep "\/opt.*"`

/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-18-1.log.gz:     66.8%
/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-18-2.log.gz:     83.1%
/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-19-1.log.gz:     70.3%
/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-19-2.log.gz:     72.9%
/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-20-1.log.gz:     73.3%
/opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/2018-08-17-3.log.gz:     90.2%
```

How can I maintain the sort order while unzipping these files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used the `-print0` option with `find`, and `-0` with `xargs`, but you forgot to use `-z` for `sort`, so `sort` essentially sees a single line (unless your filenames contain `\n`). The output you see with `ls` is probably `ls` doing some sorting.

```
find /opt/minecraft/wonders/logs/ -name '20*' -type f -mtime -3 -print0 |
  sort -z | xargs -r0 gunzip -vc | grep /opt
```

(Note: `20*` is a glob and needs to be quoted for the shell so it's passed literally to `find`, you don't want to escape `/` for `grep`, what that does is unspecified, no need for `.*` at the end of the regexp if all you want is print the matching line)

Comment: @JesseYishai If the answer helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer ! :)